# Does "constant reconfiguration" of something implies that the thing changes periodically?

Tags: ielts

There is one sentence like: *We know little about the constant reconfiguration of the coastline.* Does this statement mean that coastline changes periodically or it doesn't change periodically?

I guess that reconfiguring something means changing something to different form.
And the context of the paragraph from where this statement has been taken suggest to me that reconfiguration happens quite periodically.

Please refer Q-18 of reading section of the IELTS practice test Vol.2
https://ieltsonlinetests.com/4429534/result/ielts-recent-actual-test-answers-vol-2-reading-practice-test-2

Comment: yes, it is "always changing".

Comment: Also note, Constant and Periodic could be considered contradictory. Constant means always, and Periodic means occasionally, or on a schedule (where the Period is the time between occurrences).  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/periodic https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constant (#3).

Comment: @FrankThomas *"The rate of change is a constant.*" Constant doesn't mean *always*; it means *steady* or *invariable*. (Nor does periodic mean *occasionally*; it means *cyclically* or *repeatedly*.)

Comment: So @Frank Thomas, does it mean that coastline is changing very frequently and not periodically?

Comment: @VaibhavSharma, that is correct. it changes very frequently.

Comment: @JasonBassford, you are reading the wrong definition of constant, and applying it incorrectly in this statement. See #2 here: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/constantly . the state of changing is the constant. the changes will never stop. their occurrence is constant and unrelenting, hence "Always". And for that matter see #3 here https://www.dictionary.com/browse/periodically . Periodically can definitely mean occasionally or irregularly.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma *Constant reconfiguration* says nothing about whether or not the change is *necessarily* happening in a periodic fashion. (No matter how you interpret *periodic*.)

Comment: My apologies for not checking with this thread for a long time. @JasonBassford and FrankThomas, thanks for helping me out in this and clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sentence means that the reconfiguration of the coastline **is constant**, and we know little about it.

In this context, "constant" means happening continuously, constantly, all the time.

As already commented, "periodically" means something that is happening occasionally or on a regular interval. This is different to "constantly" which means all the time, always.

This is probably the source of the sentence fragment:
https://www.ielts-mentor.com/reading-sample/academic-reading/2730-coastal-archaeology-of-britain

Comment: Yes @halfnuts, you are right about the source of the sentence. Anyways, thanks for your answer. It has cleared my doubt further.